# XML namespace doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have tried to access my XML element and I can retrieve my data but not the namespace values.
I'm trying to retrieve the value of the fromPrice value (24.95) Can someone please help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<product ID="14">
<name>Productname</name>
<price currency="EUR">9.95</price>
<URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
<images>
<image>image.jpg</image>
</images>
<description><![CDATA[<p>long description</p>]]></description>
<categories/>
<properties>
<property name="brand">
<value>Brandname</value>
</property>
<property name="deliveryTime">
<value>1 - 3 days</value>
</property>
<property name="fromPrice">
<value>24.95</value>
</property>
<property name="EAN">
<value>12345</value>
</property>
<property name="sku">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="shipping_costs">
<value>6.95</value>
</property>
</properties>
<variations/>
</product>
</products>
<!-- Total number of products: 1 -->
```

I have tried to access my data with simpleXML and PHP:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("cache/file.xml");
if (!$data){die();}
else{
foreach($data->product as $record )
{
//Use that namespace
$namespaces = $record->properties->getNameSpaces(true);
$dc = $record->properties->children($namespaces['property']); 
$priceold = $dc->fromPrice;
}
}
echo 'priceold: '.$priceold.'<br />';
```

But that doesn't work :( can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any namespaces in your XML. Anyhow the simplest/shortest way to accomplish what you want is to use XPath. Here's a [solution](http://codepad.org/Wpecczte):

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product ID="14">
        <name>Productname</name>
        <price currency="EUR">9.95</price>
        <URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
        <images>
            <image>image.jpg</image>
        </images>
        <description><![CDATA[<p>long description</p>]]></description>
        <categories />
        <properties>
            <property name="brand">
                <value>Brandname</value>
            </property>
            <property name="deliveryTime">
                <value>1 - 3 days</value>
            </property>
            <property name="fromPrice">
                <value>24.95</value>
            </property>
            <property name="EAN">
                <value>12345</value>
            </property>
            <property name="sku">
                <value />
            </property>
            <property name="shipping_costs">
                <value>6.95</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <variations />
    </product>
</products>
XML;

$sxe   = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$value = current($sxe->xpath('//property[@name="fromPrice"]/value'));

echo $value;
```

#### Output:

```
24.95
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no namespaces in your XML. I assume you mean the `name` attribute of the `<property>` node:

```
<property name="fromPrice">
```

**To access attributes you do *not* know by name, use `attributes()`:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$properties = $xml->xpath("//property");
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    foreach($property->attributes() as $a => $b)
        echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

This code will...
(1) select all `<property>` nodes (with `xpath`) and
(2) print out each nodes's attribute name(s) and value(s)

see this working: http://3v4l.org/Rkuqf
[see the manual on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

**If you know the name of the attribute you want to access**, use `xpath` as shown by *Rolando Isidoro* in the other answer to your question.

Comment: Rolando and not Ronaldo like the players :p